Using placement new on underaligned buffer in C++
Given a buffer
char buf[sizeof(T) + alignof(T) - 1];
Is calling placement new that constructs an instance of T on the pointer to the first element of buf that is located at an address which is a multiple of alignof(T) valid? From my understanding it should be, since the pointer passed to the operator is aligned properly. I'm just unsure whether the fact that buf's alignment is still 1 (I think.) will be an issue.
I've tried it and it seemed to work, given the destructor was called properly. The keyword is seemed to however. I'd like someone more knowledgeable to give some input on this issue.

if your buffer is statically sized like that, it should work for case of one object. For implicit creation in free storage there is std::aligned_alloc since C++17. Note that you cannot delete that object made by placement-new, you have to call destructor directly.

I was actually thinking about allocating different objects in the same static buffer, but sizing it to the size and alignment of the types with the maximum values for both of them.

How do you know which element is properly aligned?

Since the buffer is sizeof(T) + alignof(U) - 1 bytes wide (where T is the max size type and U is the max alignment type I can always align any of types from template<class... Args> to the strictest aligment (alignof(U)). That gives me the alignof(U) - 1 bytes of padding. I can store the index of the type in the Args parameter pack in one of these bytes. Then a template<class T, class... Types> void CallDestructor(uint8_t Index, uint8_t Current = 0) function or a similar one can take care of calling the proper Type's function by using recursion in the implementation.

Ah, my apologies. You mean how to know which memory address is the aligned one. Well, you can calculate it using the modulo operator: uintptr_t address = reinterptret_cast<uinptr_t>(static_cast<void*>(buf)); std::size_t offset = address % alignof(U) == 0 ? 0 : alignof(U) - address % alignof(U) or,  since alignments are powers of 2, a bit more optimized operation: std::size_t offset = address + alignof(U) - 1 & ~(alignof(U) - 1);. Given the same assumption of U being the type requiring the strictest alignment from Args.
